# getting BOTH email and givenName+familyName from google oAuth2 php module

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I am using this page code:https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/a88dcec6833ac2de4798c13a24abe30c90feb057/examples/idtoken.php to get email address and givenName and familyName from Google for Google sign in purpose.

If I'm setting the scope to `email` I do get the email stored in Google account (not the one in Google plus). If I'm setting the scope to 'profile' I do get the givenName and familyName stored in Google not in Google plus profile. I need this name because most users don't have a Google Plus profile.

I tried combining them but I get either email or Name, never both.

- I tried `$client->setScopes('profile','email');` -- it only brings Name, not email
- I tried `$client->setScopes('email','profile');` -- it only brings email, and Name fields are empty.
- I also tried to set using `$google_client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'));`
  like here: [How to get user details corectly with google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198347/how-to-get-user-details-corectly-with-google-api) but only gets one or the other, never both. 
  It's like the setScopes doesn't add the scopes, but uses only the first in the list.

This is the code used:

```
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();

$oAuth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$oAttr = $oAuth2->userinfo->get();
$test_me = $oAuth2->userinfo_v2_me->get();;

/* the next part doesn't bring names or emails because the user doesn't have g+
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);  
$me = $plus->people->get('me');
$firstname = $me['name']['givenName'];
$lastname = $me['name']['familyName'];
*/
```

Any idea what's the proper way to combine profile and email in the setScopes to get both email and names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the answer.

Looks like the "official" github version from here (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php) is having a bug.

I found the bug posted and discussed here:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/6

Apparently the concatenation of the array inside the setScopes doesn't work properly.

There is a fork to the project and there is a version that works, but if I replace the whole Client.php file, it breaks somewhere else so I just replace the function:
(since I can't post more 2 links the forked project can be found by google the function name)

Bottom line is: I changed the function prepareScopes and now I can get both info (email and name).

Here is the function that works inside the file Client.php :

```
  public function prepareScopes()
  {
    if (empty($this->requestedScopes)) {
      foreach ($this->availableScopes as $service => $serviceScopes) {
        array_push($this->requestedScopes, $serviceScopes[0]);
      }
    }
    $scopes = implode(' ', $this->requestedScopes);
    return $scopes;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. You need to combine both of them like this:

```
$client ->setScopes('profile email');
```

Not like this

```
$client ->setScopes('profile', 'email');
```

By doing it this way you do not have to mess around with the other oAuth config files.

Comment: Hi, I tried with the space instead of comma as well. I found on some post this format, but it didn't work. Plus the new google approach is to use full URL instead of profile, email. I don't know how/if it would work if you have to send the url.